# jquery to filter table with checkboxes by checkbox state using Materialize switches

Tags: jquery, checkbox, filter, materialize

### EDITED: Changed jQuery below - Now I get the correct count in the console for the number of unchecked checkboxes with the given class (single column), but in the if statement, I still get that they are all unchecked even though 2 are checked, and 10 are unchecked in my data.

I have a table filled and created dynamically, and in some of the columns I use the Materialize switches to set values in a database.

I want to use the Materialize checkbox on these columns to filter the table down to those switches that are in the "on" position.  This is 'checked' in the html.

I have text fields on other columns and am filtering successfully with those, but I can't figure out how to reference a specific column on a row where the switch state is 'checked'.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="switch">
                Selected<br />
                <label>
                Off
                <input type="checkbox" class="isSelected" checked="    {{isSelected}}">
                <span class="lever"></span>
                On
                </label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="switch">
                Checked In<br />
                <label>
                Off
                <input type="checkbox" class="isCheckedIn" checked="    {{isCheckedIn}}">
                <span class="lever"></span>
                On
                </label>
            </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

This id done in Meteor, so the handlebar values basically give checked or false, in order to dynamically turn the switch to on based on the database value.

JQuery

```
'click .checkFilter' (event) {
    // console.log('checked or unchecked');
    var colId = event.currentTarget.id;
    var state = event.currentTarget.checked;
    $row = $('#table tr.trMainData');
    // console.log('State of ' + colId + ' is now ' + state);
    console.log($('input:checkbox.isSelected:not(:checked)').length);
    $('table tr.trInner').each(function() {
        if ($('input:checkbox.isSelected:not(:checked)')) {
            console.log('Unchecked: ' + $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(0).text()));
            $row.hide();
        } else {
            console.log('Checked' + $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(0).text()));
            $row.show();
        }
    });
```

I'm just trying to console log something now if it can detect that an item in the column is checked, and I don't even get that.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have fiddled around a ton, and found a much simpler way.

Basically replace all of:

```
$('table tr.trInner').each(function() {
    if ($('input:checkbox.isSelected:not(:checked)')) {
        console.log('Unchecked: ' + $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(0).text()));
        $row.hide();
    } else {
        console.log('Checked' + $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(0).text()));
        $row.show();
    }
});
```

with the following single line:

```
$('input:checkbox.isSelected:not(:checked)').closest('.trMainData').hide();
```

See, I have a nested `tr` in my table, so I need to hide the main row with the class `trMainData`, whereas I'm looking at `td` elements inside an inner row with class `trInner`.

So, using the line above, I identify table cells with the class `isSelected` that are not checked, and then tell the page to hide the main row using it's class with the jquery `closest()` function.

whew!